# Odd sublime text 3 graphic glitch - red and green lines

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-glitch

I have already tried uninstalling Sublime Text (version: Build 3143), restarting my computer, and downloading a fresh version, however I am still getting this weird graphic glitch.  I also try switching new themes, but weird red and green lines graphic is still there.  This does not happen to other programs, just Sublime Text 3. In the meantime, I am reverting back to Sublime Text 2 and the program works fine with no graphic glitches. I am using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6.

[image: sublime text 3 graphic glitch]

Answer (score 1):

Per the [FAQ on Build 3143](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/3-0-build-3143-faq/31798):

```
Q: My tabs, buttons or other UI elements look funny, broken, or red and
yellow! 

This indicates the currently loaded theme is referencing images that
could not be loaded. Most likely you are either:

- using a custom theme that is referencing images that are no longer 
  part of the Theme - Default package (it was redesigned)

- you have overridden the Theme - Default package – look for a file 
  named Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme and move it 
  to a safe place for backup

- you have customized the Default theme, most likely via a file 
  named Packages/User/Default.sublime-theme – move it to a safe 
  place for backup
```

In particular, this problem is caused by the theme engine being told to display graphics that it was unable to load. In those cases it uses this image in order to immediately draw attention to the fact that required theme assets are missing.

Along with theme engine enhancements, the `Default` theme was also overhauled. Many old themes (and likely all ST2 themes) are not directly compatible with this build because many of them reference graphical assets in the `Default` theme that are no longer there.

The `Default` and `Adaptive` themes that ship with Sublime Text 3 should work just fine out of the box; if they display this graphical problem, it's for the reasons noted above. Principally there are override modifications to the Theme that are making assumptions about assets.